# duplicate returns more numbers than required

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

if len(set(a)) > len(set(b)):  # finds the biggest list
    largest = a
    smallest = b
else:
    largest = b
    smallest = a

common = largest

for i in largest:
    if i not in smallest:
        common.remove(i)

print(common)
```

prints: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13]
7, 9, 10, 11, 12 shouldnt be in the list. because they
aint in the smaller list.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to get items that are in both sets, just use `set(a) & set(b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code relies on the assumption that statements like

> largest=a

copy the list a to largest. *This is not true in Python.* Rather that statement just makes largest a reference to the old list a.

Your code, to copy lists properly, should look like this:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

if len(set(a)) > len(set(b)):  # finds the biggest list
    largest = list(a)
    smallest = list(b)
else:
    largest = list(b)
    smallest = list(a)

common = list(largest)

for i in largest:
    if i not in smallest:
        common.remove(i)

print(common)
```

You will then get the result

[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

Answer (score 2):

Your line `common = largest` does not copy the values of list `largest` into a new list `common`. It rather makes it so both those variables are pointers to the *same* list. So when you loop over `largest` and remove from `common` you are modifying the list you are looping over. That is a bad idea.

Make a real copy with

```
common = largest[:]
```

or

```
common = list(largest)
```

However, a much more pythonic way to get a good list of the elements in both lists is just the single line

```
common = sorted(set(a) & set(b))
```

Note that this returns the list in sorted order, which may be different from the original order.